# Chris banes pull-to-refresh listview start refresh programmatically

Tags: android, listview, view, pull-to-refresh

I'm using Chris banes pull-to-refresh listview and got it working properly. I would like to add a bit of code in my onResume method to force the listview to perform the refresh action like is implemented on twitter.

So far I have tried

```
listView.setRefreshing()
listView.setRefreshing(true)
```

and neither works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you actually populating/initiating the listView.. I would tend to do that in `onResume` anyway.  onResume is always called.. even when its the first time the activity is launched.  if i understand you correct, setting the listviews adapter etc in onResume instead of onCreate would solve this, may even allow your activity to launch slightly quicker..

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I want to refresh this list automatically everytime onResume is called. I want to do this via the pull-to-refresh ListView so the user can see the list is being refreshed.

Comment: I have not worked with Chris banes list view.. but you could use a progress dialog on resume and again .. can you post your activity's code.. i'll take a look at the listview

Comment: Yes I could but since I already have this listView I'm trying to find if it is possible to do this.

Comment: What i am saying is even if it is not possible, The ListView should probably be built in onResume anyway. (personal opinion not by any means a fact)

Comment: even if I build the listView in onResume I still need to find a way to programmatically cause it to perform the pull action